# How to join arr1 array and arr2 array (based on arr2 array structure)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to merge two arrays.
I want to get arr1 data based on arr2 structure, how should I do it?

I tried using 3 forEach, but it doesn't work.

```
const arr1 = [{id:'1', List:[{name:'a', title:'a title'}, {name:'b', title:'b title'}]}, {id:'2', List:[{name:'c', title:'c title'}, {name:'d', title:'d title'}]}];
const arr2 = [{id:'1', name:'a'}, {id:'1', name:'b'}, {id:'2', name:'c'}];
```

I want the result below

```
newArr = [{id:'1', List:[{name:'a', title:'a title'}, {name:'b', title:'b title'}]}, {id:'2', List:[{name:'c', title:'c title'}]}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const arr1 = [{id:'1', List:[{name:'a', title:'a title'}, {name:'b', title:'b title'}]}, {id:'2', List:[{name:'c', title:'c title'}, {name:'d', title:'d title'}]}]
const arr2 = [{id:'1', name:'a'}, {id:'1', name:'b'}, {id:'2', name:'c'}]

const r = [...new Set(arr2.map(i=>i.id))].map(id=>(({id, List})=>({id, List:List.filter(({name})=>arr2.some(i=>i.id===id && i.name===name))}))(arr1.find(i=>i.id===id)))

console.log(r)
```

If you need an index added (as per comment below):

```js
const arr1 = [{id:'1', List:[{name:'a', title:'a title'}, {name:'b', title:'b title'}]}, {id:'2', List:[{name:'c', title:'c title'}, {name:'d', title:'d title'}]}]
const arr2 = [{id:'1', name:'a'}, {id:'1', name:'b'}, {id:'2', name:'c'}]

const r = [...new Set(arr2.map(i=>i.id))].map((id,c)=>(({List})=>({id, List:List.filter(({name})=>arr2.some(({id:x, name:y})=>x===id && y===name)).map((i,d)=>({...i, index: `${c}-${d}`}))}))(arr1.find(({id:x})=>x===id)))

console.log(r)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.
Can you tell me what the '{ }' in {id, List} means?

Comment: @ddon it's called destructuring https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment - it allows us to extract specific properties from an object directly

Comment: Thank you. I understood well.
Do you know how to add an index to a List? If you know, please ask again.
I want to add index like below.
newArr = [{id:'1', List:[{name:'a', title:'a title', index:'0-0'}, {name:'b', title:'b title', index:'0-1'}]}, {id:'2', List:[{name:'c', title:'c title', index:'1-0'}]}]

Comment: map, find, and filter are so difficult for me that I have to look at them several times.
I envy you being able to use the above features freely.
Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @ddon I couldn't even make my brain understand simple destructuring when I first saw it - the syntax was too odd for me. But after a while of getting used to it, now it's easy

Comment: thank you! I will try to get used to it.

Comment: I'm here again because I have a question. Is it possible to disable the logic if List is undefined?

Comment: @ddon you can change the code that says `{List}` to `{List=[]}`, and that will default the list to an empty array if it does not exist

Comment: I changed it to {List=[]} and it says 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'List').
I'll refer to it and try to solve it. Thank you so much for helping me again!

Comment: @ddon It worked when I tried it - maybe your `arr1` contains an entirely undefined object rather than one that exists but is only missing the `List` property. If you can't figure it out, put some test `arr1` and `arr2` data into your question that is causing the error, and I'll see if I can find the problem

Comment: For example, when the data of arr2 is const arr2 = [{id:'3', name:'e'}], an undefined error occurs.

Comment: @ddon ah, I see. That's when arr2 does not contain a matching record. Change `{List=[]}` to `{List=[]}={}`

Comment: This works so well. Thank you for solving the problem. By the way, can you explain what the ={} after {List=[]} means? thank you

Comment: @ddon it's called a [Default Parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters). All it means is that if the argument being passed is undefined, it defaults to `{}`. Then then there is [Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to extract the List property, and a second use of default parameters to default the List to `[]` if the List property does not exist

Comment: Thanks to you, I first learned about Default Parameter. Feels like a level up! Thank you for your kind explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution using reduce

```js
const arr1 = [{id:'1', List:[{name:'a', title:'a title'}, {name:'b', title:'b title'}]}, {id:'2', List:[{name:'c', title:'c title'}, {name:'d', title:'d title'}]}];
const arr2 = [{id:'1', name:'a'}, {id:'1', name:'b'}, {id:'2', name:'c'}];


const res = arr2.reduce((a,v)=> {
    const item = arr1.find(x=> x.id === v.id);
    const tItem =a.find(x=> x.id == v.id) || {id: v.id, List:[]};
    tItem.List = [...tItem.List,...item.List.filter(x=> x.name == v.name)]
    
    a.push({...tItem});
    return a;
    
},[])

console.log(res)
```